# Run HiveFromSpark example with MASTER=yarn-cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-emr, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to run [HiveFromSpark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.3.0/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/hive/HiveFromSpark.scala) example on my EMR Spark/Hive cluster.

### The Problem

Using [yarn-client](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html):

```
~/spark/bin/spark-submit --master yarn-client --num-executors=19 --class org.apache.spark.examples.sql.hive.HiveFromSpark  ~/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar
```

works like a charm. But, using [yarn-cluster](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html):

```
~/spark/bin/spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --num-executors=19 --class org.apache.spark.examples.sql.hive.HiveFromSpark ~/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar
```

fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:647)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

and the error message in Resource Manager says:

```
User class threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
```

Full log:

```
15/04/15 12:02:14 WARN DataNucleus.Persistence: Error creating validator of type org.datanucleus.properties.CorePropertyValidator
ClassLoaderResolver for class "" gave error on creation : {1}
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: ClassLoaderResolver for class "" gave error on creation : {1}
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.getClassLoaderResolver(NucleusContext.java:1087)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration.validatePropertyValue(PersistenceConfiguration.java:797)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration.setProperty(PersistenceConfiguration.java:714)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration.setPersistenceProperties(PersistenceConfiguration.java:693)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:273)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:247)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:225)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:416)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:223)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.<init>(HiveMetaStore.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:4944)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState(HiveContext.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf(HiveContext.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sql(HiveContext.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.sql.hive.HiveFromSpark$.main(HiveFromSpark.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.sql.hive.HiveFromSpark.main(HiveFromSpark.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:480)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.getClassLoaderResolver(NucleusContext.java:1079)
    ... 58 more
Nested Throwables StackTrace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.getClassLoaderResolver(NucleusContext.java:1079)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration.validatePropertyValue(PersistenceConfiguration.java:797)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration.setProperty(PersistenceConfiguration.java:714)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration.setPersistenceProperties(PersistenceConfiguration.java:693)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:273)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:247)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:225)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:416)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:223)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.<init>(HiveMetaStore.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:4944)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState(HiveContext.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf(HiveContext.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sql(HiveContext.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.sql.hive.HiveFromSpark$.main(HiveFromSpark.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.sql.hive.HiveFromSpark.main(HiveFromSpark.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:480)
15/04/15 12:02:14 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.    HiveMetaStoreClient
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:346)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState(HiveContext.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf(HiveContext.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sql(HiveContext.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.sql.hive.HiveFromSpark$.main(HiveFromSpark.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.sql.hive.HiveFromSpark.main(HiveFromSpark.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:480)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Unexpected exception caught.
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1193)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:223)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.<init>(HiveMetaStore.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:4944)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:171)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Persistence process has been specified to use a ClassLoaderResolver of name "datanucleus" yet this has   not   been found by the DataNucleus plugin mechanism. Please check your CLASSPATH and plugin specification.
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:283)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:247)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:225)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:416)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
    ... 49 more
15/04/15 12:02:14 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient)
```

### Cluster Setup

#### EMR config

I setup the cluster with `Install Spark` (s3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/install-spark) bootstrap action and `Setup Hive` step.

```
JAR location: s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar
Main class: None
Arguments: s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/hive-script --base-path s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/ --install-hive --hive-versions 0.13.1
```

#### Software versions

`hadoop version`

```
Hadoop 2.4.0-amzn-3
Subversion http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/ -r d99c64d21bf338dcdd524bd08d7c393b6d1ac1d8
Compiled by Elastic MapReduce on 2015-02-11T20:22Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 6c725ed23b3ecb95921fe461587fccf
This command was run using /home/hadoop/.versions/2.4.0-amzn-3/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.4.0-amzn-3.jar
```

Spark version

```
Spark 1.3.0 built for Hadoop 2.4.0
Build flags: -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests -Pkinesis-asl -Pspark-ganglia-lgpl -Phadoop-provided -Phive -Phive-thriftserver
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the datanucleus jars using `--jars` option when you submit and also add `hive-site.xml` to the driver-classpath so that spark can read hive configuration.

```
--jars spark/lib_managed/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,spark/lib_managed/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,spark/lib_managed/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,spark/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar --files hive/conf/hive-site.xml
```

Comment: Note idea in answer is correct but path may need to be adjusted based on distribution/installation.

Comment: this is known issue. see [SPARK-2624](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2624)

Comment: @ChristopherB : When I add the path in  my library it says that the files not found while running the app in the cluster

Answer (score 0):

For me hadooped's answer actually failed with an error of:

```
15/06/02 17:41:41 ERROR Datastore.Schema: Failed initialising database. Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true, username = hive. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception:
------ java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

But it worked when I removed the hive-site.xml file argument and used the proper paths (for EMR as of 2015-6-1):

```
--jars spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar
```

Comment: Also note that if intending to use the common metastore on the master node the connection string will need to be adjusted. With Spark 1.3.1 on EMR this works: change hive-site.xml to internal fqdn of master, grant hive user perm for external hosts, use these options with spark-submit: --driver-class-path /home/hadoop/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/home/hadoop/spark/lib/datanucleu s-core-3.2.10.jar:/home/hadoop/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/home/hadoop/spark/classpath/emr/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:hive-site.xml --files /home/hadoop/spark/conf/ hive-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
I faced the same issue while executing Spark Hive code.

Spark version 2.0.2

Hive version 1.2.1

The issue got fixed when I added following jars and hive-site.xml to the classpath:

/usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/spark2/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,   
/usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/spark2/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,   
/usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/spark2/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar
```