# ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, sbt-assembly

I'm getting error when I run Spark job on yarn cluster. I made jar couple of times and ran successfully. I don't know this time I'm not able to run even a simple WordCount program.
Here is the error that I'm getting.

```
16/04/06 20:38:13 INFO cluster.YarnClusterSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.8
16/04/06 20:38:13 INFO cluster.YarnClusterScheduler: YarnClusterScheduler.postStartHook done
16/04/06 20:38:13 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$setConf(TorrentBroadcast.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1051)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.hadoopFile(SparkContext.scala:761)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:589)
    at com.demo.WordCountSimple$.main(WordCountSimple.scala:24)
    at com.demo.WordCountSimple.main(WordCountSimple.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:480)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec.<init>(CompressionCodec.scala:152)
    ... 21 more
16/04/06 20:38:13 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: null)
16/04/06 20:38:13 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Invoking sc stop from shutdown hook
16/04/06 20:38:13 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/metrics/json,null}
16/04/06 20:38:13 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/kill,null}
```

I am using Spark 1.6.0 with Scala 2.11.7 and my sbt is as below-

```
import sbt.Keys._

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "SparkTutorials",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.7",
    mainClass in Compile := Some("WordCountSimple")
  )

exportJars := true
fork := true

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.6.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.6.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.0")

assemblyJarName := "WordCountSimple.jar"
//
val meta = """META.INF(.)*""".r

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last endsWith ".html" => MergeStrategy.first
  case n if n.startsWith("reference.conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
  case n if n.endsWith(".conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
  case meta(_) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

During jar submit, I'm doing like this-

```
./bin/spark-submit --class  com.demo.WordCountSimple  --master yarn-cluster  --num-executors 8 --executor-memory 4g --executor-cores 10 /users/hastimal/WordCountSimple.jar   /test/sample.txt /test/output
```

I'm doing some other stuff using Spark GraphX but as that was showing same error so I thought to do first WordCount testing. Still same error.
I followed [link](https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2016/02/23/how-to-resolve-error-yarn-applicationmaster-user-class-threw-exception-java-lang-runtimeexception-java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-metastore-hivemetastorecli/) and also [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648179/run-hivefromspark-example-with-master-yarn-cluster) but no luck. Is there any problem in Jar? or any problem in Cluster? or any problem in Dependencies?
Please help me!!

FYI: Code-

```
package com.demo

import java.util.Calendar

import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

/**
 * Created by hastimal on 3/14/2016.
 */
object WordCountSimple {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir","F:\\winutils")
    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: WordCountSimple <inputPath> <outputPath>")
      System.exit(1)
    }
    val inputPath = args(0)   //input path as variable argument
    val outputPath = args(1)  //output path as variable argument
    // Create a Scala Spark Context.
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCountSimple")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
    println("startTime "+startTime)
//    val input = sc.textFile(inputPath,8)
    val input = sc.textFile(inputPath,4)
      // Split it up into words.
    val words = input.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
    val counts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey{case (x, y) => x + y}
    counts.saveAsTextFile(outputPath)
    //counts.foreach(println(_))
    val endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
    println("endTime "+endTime)
    val totalTime = endTime.getTime-startTime.getTime
    println("totalTime "+totalTime)
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe some code would be helpful !

Comment: I added code as well!!

Comment: Can you try running the code in your spark-shell w/o yarn and performing an action after each transformation or rdd creation to isolate where the null is. The problem is in the app and not yarn.

Comment: I'm running same code in Intellij IDEA with same config and it's working but only problem is when I make cluster.

Comment: Where is your cluster ?

Comment: @eliasah My cluster is in CloudLab. https://www.cloudlab.us/

Comment: And can your cluster access your data ? Or your data is local ?

Comment: Yes. I'm able to do Hadoop MR job on that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnsatisfiedLinkError: no snappyjava in java.library.path when running Spark MLLib Unit test within Intellij](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039976/unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-snappyjava-in-java-library-path-when-running-spark-mlli)

Comment: @zsxwing FYI: I'm able to run locally in Intellij but when I submit in cluster I face error.

Comment: So the problem is your cluster environment hits the issue in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039976/unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-snappyjava-in-java-library-path-when-running-spark-mlli

Comment: I think your cluster may not install snappy-java native library. Could you try to switch to lz4 using `--conf spark.io.compression.codec=lz4`?

Comment: @zsxwing Should I do like this right? ./bin/spark-submit --class  com.demo.WordCountSimple  --master yarn-cluster  --num-executors 8 --executor-memory 4g --executor-cores 10 /users/hastimal/WordCountSimple.jar --conf spark.io.compression.codec=lz4  /test/sample.txt /test/output

Comment: Move `--conf spark.io.compression.codec=lz4` before your jar path

Comment: Thanks!! It was snappy error it helped me!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108573/discussion-between-chikumiku-and-zsxwing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem related to IO with snapply so when I submitted job like this:
`./bin/spark-submit --class  com.demo.WordCountSimple  --master yarn-cluster  --num-executors 8 --executor-memory 4g --executor-cores 10 --conf spark.io.compression.codec=lz4 /users/hastimal/WordCountSimple.jar  /test/sample.txt /test/output` I was able to do successfully!! Thanks @zsxwing